# why i cant change contents in column in R？

Tags: r, subset

```
 > data$Accepted.Final.round
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  
  1  
  1 NA  1  1  1  1
 [32] NA  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1 NA  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  
  1 
  NA  1 NA NA NA NA
 [63] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
  NA 
  NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [94] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  1 NA NA NA NA NA
```

I have a dataset column consists of NA, 1, 0. However when I try

```
 data$Accepted.Final.round[data$Accepted.Final.round==NA]<-0
```

or

```
 ifelse(data$Accepted.Final.round==1,1,0)
```

to replace NA with 0, both lines cannot work.
Could you guys think of any ways to fix this?

Comment: Nothing "equals" NA, not even NA.

Answer (score 4):

Use `is.na()` to determine if a value is `NA`. `NA` is contagious, meaning that doing operations with `NA` usually returns `NA`. That includes checking for equality with `==`, i.e. `x == NA` will always return `NA` and not `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

```
x <- c(2, NA, 2)
x[is.na(x)] <- 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The second attempt from OP was pretty close:

```
 data$Accepted.Final.round <- ifelse(is.na(data$Accepted.Final.round), 
    0 ,data$Accepted.Final.round)
```

The document for `ifelse` explains as:

> **Usages:**
>
> `ifelse(test, yes, no)`
>
> `yes` will be evaluated if and only if any element of test is `true`, and
>   analogously for `no`.
>
> Missing values (i.e. `NA`) in test give missing (`NA`) values in the result.